# asp.net fileupload not updating properly

Tags: asp.net

I have a file called img.gif.
With fileupload, it does not seem to be uploading the new file properly as the old .gif still exist.

FileUpld.SaveAs(uploadfile);

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that problem is in FileUpload, I have tested this scenario and it works like it should. Why do you think that there is a problem with uploading? Is uploaded file then hosted in IIS process?

Comment: As FileUpld.SaveAs captures the file path and I selected an image that was different. What else can it be?

Comment: There are 2 options possible. First IIS locked the file because it's beeing served so FileUpload can't save over opened file. Second is that you are looking at cached response from IIS. Check uploaded file on server file system. I think you are looking at second option.

Comment: You are right. It was a cached version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was facing this type of problem I always rename my file name as auto-increment from 1 to n.
i.e. img1.gif, img2.gif, img3.gif.

 Try this one may be this one is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I need it to be the same name though as the system looks for the same name.

Comment: Then replace your current file by your new file but not automatically, use **System.IO** for this operation.Hay do one thing, **FIRST** when you uploading a file and it is in you folder where you store uploaded files than _delete_ the previous one. **SECOND** now store your new file where you want to store.